# Show the text of checkBox in a textBox after clicking a button

Tags: c#, checkbox, textbox

After I click a button the cursor should change position to another TextBox

```
private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox1.Checked)
        txtAffiche.Text = txtAffiche.Text + Environment.NewLine + checkBox1.Text;
    else if (checkBox2.Checked)
        txtAffiche.Text = txtAffiche.Text + Environment.NewLine + checkBox2.Text;
    else if (checkBox3.Checked)
        txtAffiche.Text = txtAffiche.Text + Environment.NewLine + checkBox3.Text;
    else if (checkBox4.Checked)
        txtAffiche.Text = txtAffiche.Text + Environment.NewLine + checkBox4.Text;

}
```

Comment: I don't fully understand what should happen and what does happen instead/what does not work? Can you explain a little more please?

Comment: "affiche": no such English word

Comment: btw: is `txtAffiche` multiline? otherwise it's  not possible to add a multiline string. And is this windows forms or wpf or some other ui framework? please add the appropriate tag.

Comment: i want to affiche the text of checkBox in a textBox after clicking in a button

Comment: "affiche" = show sorry

Comment: Ok, now I understand what you want. Your code seems to do that. _What_ is the problem? Doesn't the text get displayed? Is it the wrong text? Do you get an exception? What is your question?

Comment: @taha, try to debug while checkBox1 is checked. Do you see that the line which set txtAffiche from checkBox1 is executed? if yes, checkBox1.Text is empty string or not? the txtAffiche text color is white? black?

Comment: @taha, also make sure you are not updating different TextBox that is not visible.

Comment: please i have a list of checkBox and button (ok) and textBox , i want after check some chekBox and clicking in Ok button ,the text of this checkBox showing in textBox please help me

Comment: Your code already does that - do you want to add **all Text** from **all checked CheckBoxes**? In that case, just replace your `else if` by `if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you want to add text to the `txtAffiche` `TextBox` depending on which check box(s) is/are checked? If this is the case then the if/else statements are somewhat confusing when using `CheckBoxes`. `CheckBoxes` are used to check/uncheck an individual item. When there is more than 1 `CheckBox`(s) they do NOT work as a group like radio buttons such that only ONE (1) radio button can be selected when there is more than 1. So multiple `CheckBox`’s can be checked at the same time.

The if/else/if/else statement basically sets only one (1) `checkbox.text` name even if all check boxes are checked. This if/else/if/else statement simply displays the FIRST checked box. This seems odd if there is more than one `CheckBox` checked. I am guessing you may want to display all the `CheckBox`es that are currently checked. I hope the code below may help.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  if (checkBox1.Checked)
    sb.Append(checkBox1.Text + " ");
  if (checkBox2.Checked)
    sb.Append(checkBox2.Text + " ");
  if (checkBox3.Checked)
    sb.Append(checkBox3.Text + " ");
  if (checkBox4.Checked)
    sb.Append(checkBox4.Text + " ");
  txtAffiche.Text = txtAffiche.Text + Environment.NewLine + sb.ToString();
}
```